# How to show sub document value in angular js from json object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to show a sub document object value in my html using ng-repeat. However, its showing me all the results in total. It's showing me 9 items instead of 5 for each review item.

I want to show rating property and their value but for every reviews. That means, each review will have their corresponding segmented rating.

In this image, its showing me all the rating objects.
[Current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6SRt.png)

It should be like this,[Expected Output without duplication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZsbh.png)

Bellow is the json input

```
{
_id: "591ec7a2b782de17be7d9334",
title: "Pizza Hut",
description: "pizza hut",
info: [ ],
tags: [ ],
comments: [ ],
reviews: [
{
name: "Zamiul",
userID: "591eaa9fbcd2440e7ac86f34",
title: "You wont be disappointed",
review: "I dont think, anyone would be disappointed to go in Pizza Hut with family and friends. It's really a nice place to hang out.",
_id: "5921288b4eae3d0f6f6c548a",
createdOn: "2017-05-21T05:41:31.302Z",
rating: [
{
property: "Service",
value: 9,
_id: "5921288b4eae3d0f6f6c548f"
},
{
property: "Price",
value: 7,
_id: "5921288b4eae3d0f6f6c548e"
},
{
property: "Food",
value: 9,
_id: "5921288b4eae3d0f6f6c548d"
},
{
property: "Varieties",
value: 10,
_id: "5921288b4eae3d0f6f6c548c"
},
{
property: "Place",
value: 10,
_id: "5921288b4eae3d0f6f6c548b"
}
]
},
{
name: "Zamiul",
userID: "591eaa9fbcd2440e7ac86f34",
title: "2nd review",
review: "2nd review",
_id: "592156b7657f46137076a27b",
createdOn: "2017-05-21T08:58:31.629Z",
rating: [
{
property: "Service",
value: 10,
_id: "592156b7657f46137076a27f"
},
{
property: "Price",
value: 8,
_id: "592156b7657f46137076a27e"
},
{
property: "Food",
value: 9,
_id: "592156b7657f46137076a27d"
},
{
property: "Place",
value: 6,
_id: "592156b7657f46137076a27c"
}
]
}
],
contentStatus: "active"
}
```

This is my html

```
<div ng-repeat="items in reviews">
 <div ng-repeat="item in items.rating">
<p>{{ item.property }}<p>
</div>
</div>
```

in my controller i am pulling data using a service and assigned json input from the URl as reviews.

Comment: I just read your question three times and I am stll not sure I understand it. Would you mind including your expected rendered HTML result?

Comment: From the json pasted above, i want to show each rating object with their property and value for each review. Right now with the HTML i provided, its showing me all the rating objects instead of showing only the rating objects in each review items.

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation does not really help me (and judging from the answers I'm not alone). Example output on the other hand, would be helpful.

Comment: I have edited my question's description with expected output image

Comment: Looks like you just want one box per review. Wrap your inner `ng-repeat` in a container and you're done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the edited question, you want one box with all ratings once per review. This is how you could approach it:

```
<div ng-repeat="review in reviews">
    <h1>Review {{ review.title }}</h1>
    <div class="reviewRatings">
        <div ng-repeat="rating in review.rating">
            <p>{{ rating.property }} - {{ rating.value }}<p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just figured out, I have a ng-repeat in my parent div, and thus it was not working. Thanks all ;)

Comment: @ZamiulHasan Please upvote all helpful answers and accept one if it's providing a solution.

Comment: My reputation point is less than 15 thus its recorded but not publicly displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<div ng-repeat="items in reviews.rating.property">

     <p>{{ items }}<p>

</div>
```

Comment: Could you specify further how you want your data to be displayed? I do not full understand what you want. @ZamiulHasan

Answer (score 0):

use

```html
<div ng-repeat="items in reviews">
 <div ng-repeat="(item, rating) in items.rating">
<p>{{ item }} = {{rating}}<p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its rendering the rating of two reviews , you just need a separator after each review repeat

Try this code

```
<div ng-repeat="review in reviews track by $index">
   <p> {{$index + 1}}) {{review.title}}</p>
   <p> {{review.review}}</p>
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="rating in review.rating">{{ rating.property }} : {{ 
       rating.value }} </li>
   </ul>

</div>
```

I also added a plunker check https://plnkr.co/edit/7b6s7qgEHAw8B5Q99coq?p=preview

Comment: I dont know why its working on plunker but not in my host.

Comment: i made small change in ng-repeat in html, and check the app.js in plunker